# dismissing modalViewController moves main view buttons around iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, model-view-controller

I'm using `presentModalViewController` and `dismissModalViewController` with animation set to `YES` in both cases. This works fine.

After the modal view is dismissed, all of the content on the main view has moved down what looks like 20px.

Would anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this app full screen?

I have seen some strange issues regarding apps that hide the status bar.  You may try re-hiding the status bar in viewWillAppear or viewWillDisappear on the modal.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: thanks, that as the problem, it was full screen. i had missed that part.